# Why is this loop breaking after the first iteration?

Tags: bash, loops

Trying to loop through all files in a directory, check them for the existence of a string, and add it if it doesn’ exist. This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=*
for f in $FILES
do
    echo "Processing $f file..."
    if grep -Fxq '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' $f
    then
        continue
    else
        echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' | cat - $f > temp && mv temp $f
    fi
done
```

… but the script stops after the first loop. Any ideas why?

Comment: It depends on which directory are you launching the script? Is there a file? More?

Comment: Don't use `FILES`; it is subject to parameter expansion *and* word-splitting, which will cause problems if any file names contain whitespace. Just use `for f in *`.

Comment: Where should the string be added? Your question is a bit terse in that it doesn't explain the requirement properly

Comment: `bash -x yourscript`

Comment: 1) Use the glob directly in the `for` loop. 2) Learn to use `"quotes"` around Bash expansions or you will be miserable. So everywhere you have `$f` you would use `"$f"` otherwise any file with a space in the name will look like two files to Bash.

Comment: @chepner — Ended up using `for f in *.svg`. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @chepner `$FILES` is indeed a subject to parameter expansion and word-splitting but it is completely irrelevant in this case. Please read my answer.

Comment: The loop works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to use the inplace edit option `-i` of the `sed` tool like below

```
sed -i  '1{/^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>/!{
s/^/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n/}}' /path/to/files/*
```

**What are we doing above**

- The inplace option `-i` with `sed` makes any change to the file written to the file.
- By `1{}` we are processing just the first line of the file
- The `/^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>/!` part checks if the string is **NOT**(note the ! at the end) present in the beginning of the line.
- If the above condition  is not true we substitute the beginning of the line (`^`) with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n` using

  ```
       s/^/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n/
  ```
- The rest is closing the curly brackets in the correct order :)

  ---

That said, in your original script I see variables like `FILES`. It is discouraged to use uppercase variables as user variables as they are reserved as environment variables and might lead to conflict. So use `files` instead.

Again doing

```
file=*
```

has the implication of [[ word splitting ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) and produce undesired results if you have non standard files that contain spaces or even new lines. What you could do is

```
files=( * ) # This put the files in an array
for file in "${files[@]}" # Double quoting the array prevents word splitting
do
 # Do something with "$file" but why bother when you've a one-liner with sed? ;-)
done
```

---

<sup>**Note:** For `sed` manual visit [[ here ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)</sup>

Comment: @dawg I overlooked that point.. Very true.. What he should have done was `files= ( * )` and then read values from the array like `for file in "${files[@]}"`

Comment: It is better to do `for f in in *` because `( * )` still does not allow filenames with `\n` in them. Rare, but possible.

Comment: @dawg, eh? `files=( * )` stores each glob result as a separate list entry. Newlines work fine. Maybe you're thinking of `IFS=$'\n'; files=( $(...) )`; *that*, indeed, is buggy.

Comment: Prior to morning coffee. Yes -- Charles is correct. Ignore my comment regarding `( * )`

Comment: @sjsam @dawg I think word splitting is not an issue with `FILES=*`, check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I want to clear some things up about word splitting and filename expansion I saw here in the comments.

When using variable assignment, quoting [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion), only the following expansions are done: tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion. This means that there really is just an asterisk in your variable `$files` as there is no filename expansion taking place. So at this point you don't need to worry about newlines, spaces etc. because there are no actual files in your variable. You can see this with `declare -p files`.

This is the reason you don't have to quote when assigning to a variable.

```
var=$othervariable
```

is the same as:

```
var="$othervariable"
```

Now, when you use your variable `$files` in the for loop `for f in $files` (note that you cannot quote `$files` here because the filename expansion wouldn't take place) that variable gets expanded and **undergoes word splitting**. But the actual value is **JUST**  the asterisk and word splitting won't do anything with the result! Quoting the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) again:

> After word splitting, unless the -f option has been set (see The Set
>   Builtin), Bash scans each word for the characters ‘*’, ‘?’, and ‘[’.
>   If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a
>   pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames
>   matching the pattern (see Pattern Matching).

Meaning of this is that filename expansion is done **after** variable expansion and word splitting. So the files expanded by the filename expansion won't be split by IFS! Therefore, the following code works just fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files=*
for f in $files; do
   echo "<<${f}>>"
done
```

and correctly outputs:

```
<<file    with many     spaces>>
<<filewith* weird   characters[abc]>>
<<normalfile>>
```

A shorter version of this is obviously to use `for f in *` instead of the variable `$files`. You also definitely want to quote any usage of `$f` in your loop as that expansion really does undergo the word splitting.

---

This being said, your loop should function properly.